# How Do I Use Gulp to Minify and Autoprefix CSS files from SASS/SCSS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm having trouble with my gulpfile and can't figure out what's going wrong.

Issues: autoprefixer not working as intended, and it isn't always properly outputting a .css and .min.css file as intended.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var minify = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

var config = {
    sassMain: 'style/Main.scss',
    sassFiles: 'style/**/*.scss',
    cssfiles: ['style/Main.css'],
    dest: 'style',
    autoprefixerOptions: {
    browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 5%']
    }
};

gulp.task('compile-sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.sassMain)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(prefix(config.autoprefixerOptions.browsers))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest))
        .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest))
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.watch(config.sassFiles, ['compile-sass']);
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, I recommend putting all source files into folder `src` and built files into `build`.  This works below, and you can incrementally add new pipes to see what breaks it

## gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var sass = require('gulp-sass')
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer')
var minCss = require('gulp-minify-css')
var rename = require('gulp-rename')

var config = {
   srcCss : 'src/scss/**/*.scss',
   buildCss: 'build/css'
}

gulp.task('build-css', function(cb) {
   gulp.src(config.srcCss)

      // output non-minified CSS file
      .pipe(sass({
         outputStyle : 'expanded'
      }).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildCss))

      // output the minified version
      .pipe(minCss())
      .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildCss))

   cb()
})

gulp.task('watch', function(cb) {
   gulp.watch(config.srcCss, ['build-css']) 
})

gulp.task('default', ['build-css', 'watch'])
```

## main.scss

```
$degrees: '50%';

.rotated {
    transform: $degrees;
}
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

## Resulting File Structure

Here's what you'll have after you run `$ gulp` (excludes `node_modules` folder)

```
$ tree -I node_modules
.
├── build
│   └── css
│       ├── main.css
│       └── main.min.css
├── gulpfile.js
├── package.json
└── src
    └── scss
        └── main.scss

4 directories, 5 files
```

## My Environment

```
$ node -v
v5.1.0

$ npm -v
3.3.12

$ gulp -v
[13:39:54] CLI version 1.0.0
[13:39:54] Local version 3.9.0
```

Comment: I tried stripping it down to this:
`.pipe(sass())`

`.pipe(gulp.dest(config.destDir))`

But it's still not working. Could there be something wrong with my npm/node packages? My original Gulpfile.js was working last week.

node `5.1.0` and npm `3.3.12`

Comment: Try using my code exactly as I wrote and tested it.  Then add more code on incrementally if needed.

Comment: I tried that. Getting the same thing. Definitely looks like something screwy happened with my node and npm packages

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: This is going to sound really stupid but I'm boggled so I'm just going to put myself out there and ask this: I'm getting this error when I try to remove node_modules: `Remove-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'rf'.` Thanks for all the help by the way.

Comment: `$ ...` typically indicates a linux command.  I'll assume you're on Windows: `c:\...\project> rmdir node_modules`.  In otherwords, delete `node_modules` and run `npm install` again. Then run `gulp`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.

Was eventually able to resolve the issue by reinstalling Node, NPM, node-sass, and gulp, then rebuilding the whole thing.

Comment: This was a nice find on Google.  One comment - `gulp-minify-css` is deprecated and has introduces at least one security vulnerability (https://npmjs.com/advisories/785) at the time of this comment.  Use of `gulp-clean-css` is now recommended.

Comment: This is awesome and I like how it is one task to generate the expanded and compressed styles, but can you also generate sourcemaps for the minified version of the stylesheet? @AnthumChris